# Node ECONNRESET tunnel-ssh and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ssh

When I start Express, it crashes in about 5 minutes.

Use this dependencies.

- express 4.17.1
- mongoose 5.9.7
- tunnel-ssh 4.1.4

wait about 5 min after, got an error like this.

```
[nodemon] starting `node bin/www`
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:201:27)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at Client.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/project/node_modules/tunnel-ssh/node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js:294:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  level: 'client-socket'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

DB connect.

```
module.exports.A = async () => {
  this.ssh = await tunnel({
    keepAlive: true,
    host: HOST,
    username: USERNAME,
    privateKey: fs.readFileSync(KEY),
    dstHost: DST_Host,
    dstPort: DST_Port
  })

  mongoose.connect(URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
  })
}

module.exports.B = async () => {
  this.ssh.close()
}
```

SSH config.

```
Host *
  ClientAliveInterval 8
  ServerAliveInterval 60
  TCPKeepAlive yes
```

Comment: and what is the question? Quite often ssh tunnels break when nothing gets transmitted through them. please extend your question with code which sets up ssh tunnel. Also look into option ["keepAlive:true"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tunnel-ssh) . Also at server side you can tweak /etc/ssh/sshd_config to enable [heartbeats](http://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ClientAliveInterval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

```
  mongoose.connect(URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 30000, // Use this.
    socketTimeoutMS: 30000 // Use this.
  })
```